# How to do Jenkins with Selenium and Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, jenkins

Maybe because most build servers are linux and so irrelevant or most people use slaves, but I'm finding not much information for this problem.

I have a jenkins server on Windows Server 2012. I'm trying to run Selenium tests on it(for a Vaadin app if it matters). It's great under Chrome and Firefox, but for IE it doesn't seem to want to do anything. This works fine on the desktop. Some investigation found the selenium site saying the Selenium IE WebDriver doesn't work under services. Fine so I tried to run it from the command line(java -jar jenkins.war), but when I start jenkins it doesn't have any of my existing jobs.

So I have one multipart question: (1) What's the best way to do selenium tests for IE on jenkins? and (2) if it's to start jenkins from the command line, what's the best way to do that?

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. stop the jenkies slav service
2. Open a browser on the slave machine and go to the Jenkins master server url (http://yourjenkinsmaster:8080).
   Go to Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes, Click on the slave machine. 
   3.run in cmd the line in option: run frome slave commandline For example:
   javaws http://{yourjenkinsmaster}:8080/computer/{slav name}/slave-agent.jnlp

new jenkies run whith GUI and ie run ok

to run it all day :
save this line in bat file in startup folder

Comment: This sounds like a very sound plan, but unfortunately I'm not using slaves. I'm running the builds/tests on Master. I'm not seeing a way to add a command line to Master.

Comment: I ultimately made the master also contain the slave by running the Java Web Start on an account on master. Unfortunately this means I need to keep that script running continuously on that account and if the server goes down I need to manually run that script again. The other options for running the slave seemed to still mean it was running under a service, which is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: This absolutely saved me from loosing all my hair. I am not sure why there is no mention of IE not working when the Jenkins slave is running as a service. Need to figure out a way to keep that script running in the background all the time without stumbling into this issue again.